# Out Of Range Exception при заполнении DataGridView

Tags: winforms, visual-basic, исключения, datagrid, datagridview

Помогите пожалуйста, почему всё время программа вылетает с ошибкой выхода за границу массива на том месте, где в DataGrid заносятся значения из массива?!

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim A(,) As Integer, n As Integer, m As Integer
        Dim i As Integer, j, Gl, Pob As Integer

        Randomize() 'Иницилизация генератора случайных чисел
        m = InputBox("Введите число строк", , 10)
        n = InputBox("Введите число столбцов", , 10)

        ReDim A(0 To m, 0 To n) ' Размеры матрицы А -  m-строк, n-столбцов
        For i = 0 To m
            For j = 0 To n
                A(i, j) = Int(Rnd() * 21 - 10) 'Заполняем матрицу случайными числами
            Next j
        Next i

        DataGridView1.ColumnCount = n
        DataGridView1.RowCount = m

        For i = 0 To m
            'Идём по столбцам в строке'
            For j = 0 To n
                DataGridView1.Item(i, j).Value = A(i, j)
            Next j
        Next i

        For i = 0 To m
            For j = 0 To n
                If i = j Then Gl = Gl + A(i, j) ' считаем главную диагональ
                If i = m - j + 1 Then Pob = Pob + A(i, j) ' считаем побочную диагональ
            Next j
        Next i

        MsgBox("Сумма элементов главной диагонали = " & Gl, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Вывод ответа")
        MsgBox("Сумма элементов побочной диагонали = " & Pob, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Вывод ответа")
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если массив от 0, то до m - 1 и n - 1

Comment: То есть, в цикле надо бежать до m - 1? Тогда почему на первом цикле программа не падает, а на втором - падает?

Comment: neo, Вы разве не услышали как на первом цикле программа скрежетала зубами. Перенапряглась.